# Problem in loading image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

Hi Iam loading image at runtime.I have the problem where i have to place the image in folder.Actually i put it in folder named as Image.But it shows the error that it can not find image in folder *...bin\debug\HH.bmp.*

So i pasted it in debug folder and works fine.
But when i take EXE out of Debug folder and when i run it,it does not work.
Why?
Then how can i add image in such case?

Is there any way to add image in resource file, Like in MFC..

```
src1 = @"HH.bmp";
Img1.Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(src1 ) as ImageSource;
```

Comment: It show me the error
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WpfApp;component\data\HH.png'.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to another question.  Check out [WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

**EDIT**

```
<Image Source="../Images/icon.png" />
```

Comment: I used like "src1 = @"pack://application:,,,/WpfApp;component/data/HH.bmp";Its works fine.But when i convert it to Control Library,it didnot works.It shows error.that cannot load assembly

Comment: Can you set the image property in the XAML instead?  The way we do it here is to set it like I have in the edit of my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you run this application will search the image in the current Assembly directory. just try like this
`<Image source="/yournamespace;component/Images/Close.png">` there should be an image folder with close.png in the solution. No need of the image or image folder in the debug folder.

Comment: It show me the error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WpfApp;component\data\HH.png'.
And im doing this in C# coding not in XAML

Comment: k just try this

ImgControl.Source=new BitmapImage(new URI(@"/yournamespace;component/Images/Close.png",UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

Set the [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")] to "en" culture in AssemblyInfo.cs file. Check your assembly resource culture!

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```