# Handle MouseLeftButtonDown event for Image in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn

In my `DataGrid` i have a column that contains an `Image` created like this:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgView" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/View.png" />
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To handle events from my View in my View Model i am using the namespace:

> xmlns:intr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

On a normal `Image` i can handle the event like this:

```
    <Image Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/View.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150">
        <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
            <intr:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewImageMouseDownCommand}"/>
            </intr:EventTrigger>
        </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

And it works just fine, yet when i add the same code to my `Image` in the `DataGridTemplateColumn` like this:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgViewCompany" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/View.png">
                            <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <intr:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewImageMouseDownCommand}"/>
                                </intr:EventTrigger>
                            </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried a method i found here : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478643/Mouse-Event-Commands-for-MVVM

Which also didn't work on the `Image` in the `DataGridTemplateColumn`

My ViewModel :

```
class vmCompaniesList: vmBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DataView CompaniesListView { get; private set; }
    private vwCompanyListDataTable CompaniesList { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand<Image> ViewImageMouseDownCommand { get; private set; }

    public vmCompaniesList()
    {
        ViewImageMouseDownCommand = new RelayCommand<Image>(ViewImageMouseDown);
        using (vwCompanyListTableAdapter taCompanies = new vwCompanyListTableAdapter())
        {
            CompaniesList = taCompanies.GetData();
            CompaniesListView = CompaniesList.DefaultView;
        }
    }

    private void ViewImageMouseDown(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

So i am wondering how i can handle the event?

EDIT: So i have tried, according to the possible duplicate post, to add my `Image` to a `Button` and subscribing to the click but still no joy, i am wondering if it is to do with it being inside the `DataGridTemplateColumn`

This is what i tried :

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgViewCompany" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding ViewImageMouseDownCommand}">
                            <Image Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/View.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgViewCompany" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding ViewImageMouseDownCommand}">
                            <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewImageMouseDownCommand}"/>
                                </intr:EventTrigger>
                            </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Image Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/View.png" />
                        </Button>                                    
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

EDIT 2: Thanks to ASh this is what got it working:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="imgViewCompany" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/AlphaCureCRM(WPF);component/Resources/View.png">                                
                        <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <intr:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewImageMouseDownCommand, 
                                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                </intr:EventTrigger>
                            </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Image Command Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885007/wpf-image-command-binding)

Comment: I read that question and didn't think it answered my problem, but now however i am thinking if i can put my image on a button inside the `DataGridTemplateColumn` then maybe that would work. I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseBinding` should reduce markup required to bind command to click event. However the issue is probably incorrect command binding. `ViewImageMouseDownCommand` is not in the DataGridRow DataContext (single element of DataView, `DataRowView`).  Try bind to DataGrid DataContext:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewImageMouseDownCommand, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```