# Show an Image resource in a WPF window defined in a class library

Tags: wpf, resources

I have seen this thread: [WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources) and applied the information there. But my situation seems a bit more tricky:

- Assembly `A` is a class library

  - contains `Dialog.xaml`

    - this is a WPF window
  - contains `Images/i.gif`
- Assembly `B` is a WPF application

  - shows `Dialog.xaml`

In my dialog, I have tried specifying the image in the following ways:

```
<Image Source="/Images/i.gif"/>
```

and

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/i.gif"/>
```

both work, **but only in the designer**!

Next, I added two and two together to yield:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,A;;content/Images/i.gif"/>
```

but this shows the same symptoms:

As soon as I start the application, the images seem to be not found. I don't know for sure, since I get no error message. They just don't show up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You appear to be missing the required word "Component" form the beginning of your path, e.g.

> pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly.Name;**Component**/Images/PlusGreen.png

Comment: Thanks, I got confused. You saved my day!

Comment: @Daren That's nice to know. Happy to help. :)