# WPF: Accessing an embedded resource in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, embedded-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

I have some images in my **VS C#** project that are declared as embedded resources. I'm accessing them in the .cs file using:

```
Stream logoStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjNS.Image.logo.png");
Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(logoStream);
```

But how can I access my logo in the .xaml file?

Comment: "But how can I access my logo in the .xaml._**cs**_ file?" Are you actually talking about the cs file ? or did you mean the xaml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Call the Resource like this;

```
<Image Source="Resources/ProjNS.Image.logo.png" height="100" width="100"/>
```

Comment: Hm, it still looks for an absolute path: 'Path D:\ ... \logo.png not found.'