# How to assign an embedded image resource to an image control in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF. How I can use embedded resource image for an image control in WPF using XAML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF image resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add Image to your project then set Build Action to Resource
2. Add Image to your xaml, e.g. `<Image Source="YourImage.jpg" />`