# C# WPF Images are not loading

Tags: c#, wpf, image

i have this small problem,i have an WPF executable with lots of images,and it loads only on local computer (on the one the exe was made) the rest of computers see only text,no imgs,i saw that the imgs url are on the local's computers,so my question is : how can i load them from the images image? as it gives the error : property value is not valid everytime i select the images from the Images dir from source.

Comment: I don't have CODE !! only xml...so i need to load images from code,how do i do that?

Comment: Show xml in this case! What I mean is that we cannot help you to diagnose your problem if we don't see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

If just shown on development PC then you need either add them as [embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources) or make sure to copied them into the assembly folder before deployment.

Comment: void LoadImages()
        {
            
           BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"9XFfD.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        }

Comment: @CatalinMihai Independent of how you are displaying the image (using XAML or C#) the problem is with the path to the image. Look on google how to add embedded resources into your wpf project and do it that way.