# wpf image not being shown in some ListBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf

I Have a `ListBox` with an `ItemTemplate` defined as follows. My problem is the image is shown in only one item per type. i.e:

[image]

How do I make all the items show their relevant status?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl x:Name="status">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="NotDownloaded">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Image Source="/Images/help-file24.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Downloaded">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Image Source="/Images/file-complete24.png""/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Error">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Image Source="/Images/file-warning24.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}" Margin="5,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources) on stackoverflow

> If you will use the image in multiple places, then it's worth loading
>   the image data only once into memory and then sharing it between all
>   Image elements.
>
> To do this, create a BitmapSource as a resource somewhere:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="../Media/Image.png" />
```

> Then, in your code, use something like:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}" />
```

> In my case, I found
>   that I had to set the Image.png file to have a build action of
>   Resource rather than just Content. This causes the image to be carried
>   within your compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

`Image` is an `UIElement`, meaning it's part of the hierarchy of controls and can only have one parent at any given time.

What your template is doing is set the same `Image` control instance as the content of many `ContentControl`. So it only works for the very first `ContentControl`, and then fails as `Image` has already a parent.

You may try to replace your `ContentControl` with an `Image` and setting `Image`'s source in your `DataTrigger`s.