# Button using dependency properties for a separate image per state

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dependency-properties

I have a `Button` control that I want to be able to reuse throughout project.  Each time button enters a new state, a different image will be displayed.  For now, I have `Normal State` and `Pressed State`.

Here's the XAML portion of the control:

```
<Button
    x:Class="customImageButton.ImageButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Grid>
            <ContentControl Width="80">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="Normal" Source="{Binding NormalState}"/>
                    <Image Name="Pressed" Source="{Binding PressedState}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
         </Grid>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Here's the code-behind for the control:

```
namespace customImageButton
{
    public partial class ImageButton : Button
    {
        public ImageButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ImageSource NormalState
        {
            get { return base.GetValue(NormalStateProperty) as ImageSource; }
            set { base.SetValue(NormalStateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NormalState", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));

        public ImageSource PressedState
        {
            get { return base.GetValue(PressedStateProperty) as ImageSource; }
            set { base.SetValue(PressedStateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PressedState", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));
    }
}
```

...and here is its use:

```
<local:ImageButton Content="CustomButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" NormalState="Resources/Normal.png"
                   PressedState="Resources/Pressed.png"/>
```

My problem is that the images I've provided are not displaying.  The `Build Action` for both images is `Resource` and I have tried using absolute path; however, that provided the same result.  What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the answers here (make sure you also read the comments): [WPF image resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

Comment: @elgonzo Implying that I haven't done that?  That link does not assist me in any way.  It's not a problem of managing the resources.

Comment: The bindings should use `TemplateBinding`, as in `Source="{TemplateBinding NormalState}"`.

Comment: @McGarnagle I get `The member "NormalState" is not recognized or is not accessible.` if I do that

Comment: Oh, you also need `TargetType="{x:Type my:ImageButton}"` in the control template.

Comment: @McGarnagle That wouldn't even be a valid code.

Comment: Was using Silverlight syntax -- but the point is, your control template has to target your `ImageButton` type.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know ... I posted that as an answer, because it works.  Visual Studio does complain about it though.  You should probably place your default style and its control template in `/Themes/Generic.xaml`, instead of inline like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with the code as listed:

1. The bindings need to be `TemplateBinding`.
2. The `TargetType` should refer to the "ImageButton" type, not `Button`.

Like this:

```
<ControlTemplate 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:customImageButton"
     TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
     <Grid>
        <ContentControl Width="80">
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="Normal" Source="{TemplateBinding NormalState}"/>
                <Image Name="Pressed" Source="{TemplateBinding PressedState}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
     </Grid>
```

**Note:** The above builds and runs, but Visual Studio complains:

> 'ImageButton' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'Button'.

I suggest putting the control template in its own Style in the `Themes/Generic.xaml` resource dictionary, rather than inline.

Comment: You're the man! :)  At first I thought you were crazy in the above comment exchange, but you're actually 100% right.  Thanks for your patience and your time.  I'll look into making the control template a resource, thanks.

Comment: Just as an update: I followed your suggestion regarding moving the template into the `Generic.xaml` and the error went away.  Thanks again.