# Failing to load resources from dynamically loaded assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main application, which loads plugins from "./plugins" directory.

The plugins are library assemblies containing UserControls, which use some images (resources).

The problem is that the images are not found when used in the main application.

```
XamlParseException -> Cannot locate resource 'X.png'
```

I tried building the resources as "Resource", "Embedded Resource" and "Content", but the exception still persists.

I tried specifying the path to images as

```
/X.png
```

and also as (neither works)

```
pack://application:,,,/<PluginAssemblyName>;X.png
```

How should I build the image resources so that they are available even after loading the assembly as plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292)? The `Assembly` would be the one you've loaded programmatically.

Also take care and make the resource *accessible* (much like a `class` is declared `public`), otherwise it cannot be referenced from outside the assembly.

More about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0tyye07.aspx).

Comment: There is no way to set the image resource as public, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are not missing something. What I meant was declaring it *accessible* which is *as if* a `class` is made `public`. For images I've added an edit above to explain how to do it, but I guess this is not your concern anymore as you've solved the problem on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the as Resource and try to use the below pack URI syntax. For the resources in the other assembly you should use the /AssemblyName;component syntax

```
"pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/x.png"
```

Comment: Is there a difference between those two syntaxes?

Comment: The difference is your URI type whether is relative or absolute. For more info refer MSDN  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames` to get a listing of all the resources and the names they have, which will let you know what name(s) to use to retrieve your resource(s).

Comment: I tried this, but the images were not listed there, only "WpfApp.g.resource" and "WpfApp.Properties.Resources.resources".

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416464/2649340

In the plugin assembly I use this path to reference the image resource

```
"/«YourAssemblyName»;component/«YourPath»/«YourImage.png»"
```

and even while this plugin is loaded in another assembly, it loads correctly.