# Resource images reloading on app start

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I have C# application with some images in WPF elements. Just like that:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/back.png" />
</Grid.Background>
```

They are embedded with compilation, so, there's no way to modify picture without rebuilding a project. I want my programm to load images from disk on start to make them changeable without recompile. I know this could be done with special loaders (like `Image.FromFile` for example). But this way all the pictures must be added to stage in C# code after loading, not in WPF. Is there a way to do this simplier? Maybe a resource property or something like this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources) might help you.

Comment: @Shakra Thaks, this is exactly what I need.