# Changing WPF window icons

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have a bunch of icons as resources. Managed to change `MainWindow` icon without issues, but doing the same thing on others gives me this error:

`Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\resources\add.ico'`

I have this in the top section of XAML file:

```xml
Icon="resources/add.ico"
```

So - for some reason it searches for resources in resources folder when in `MainWindow.xaml`, but in other window it decides to search in VS folder (for unknown reason). How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use absolute paths using a WPF Pack-URI.
These posts explain it quite well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416464/10724593
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/aa970069(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

For you it would be 
`pack://application:,,,/resources/add.ico`

The basic syntax for it is `pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml`
as stated on the MSDN Article

Comment: Link only answers should be considered as comments, not the answers

Comment: Works flawlessly. It appears that MainWindow accepts simplified path, while other windows demand 'expanded' version. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the image in multiple places, then it's worth loading the image data only once into memory and then sharing it between all `Image` elements.

To do this, create a `BitmapSource` as a resource somewhere:

`<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="../Media/Image.png" />`

Then, in your code, use something like:

`<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}" />`

In my case, I found that I had to set the `Image.png` file to have a build action of `Resource` rather than just `Content`. This causes the image to be carried within your compiled assembly.

For more information look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources/2416464#2416464)

Comment: It's already set as Resource. I can do what i want in MainWindow, but any other window refuses to accept it.

Comment: Try using ```<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}" />``` and change it to work for an icon